# Android - how to open an audio-stream url with an external app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to give the user the choice of opening an audio stream url with an audio player that he already have installed.

The following code works as so far that the user getting a list of installed audio apps and can choose between then.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(stream.getAudio()), "audio/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

But it will open an intent that lives inside my app only. Therefor the playback will stop if the user closes my app. How can I change the behaviour so that not an new activity is started but the whole app is launched and is detached from my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's because the audio player is opened in the same task stack of your app.
Try [`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) to start it as a new task, like:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

See [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) to learn more.